# Flutter, Column center inside Column start?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(),
                          Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                      //I want it to be center
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text("1234",)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

It seems 2nd Column is not working (MainAxisAl.center)

is there a way to achieve that? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `Column` widget is actually centered, but you used a `Row` widget that will take all the horizontal space available.

The result is that your `Text` widget is on the right side.

You can probably wrap your `Row` and second `Column` with `Flexible` widgets.

Here's the official documentation of `Flexible` widget:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Comment: the result Text widget is not on the right side but Flexible works